# protractor, JavaScript Comparison: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, protractor

var Operation= require('./1.js');

var ExpectedResults = require('./range.js');

describe("Range Test", function() {

```
Operation.min.forEach(function(elt, i) {

    ExpectedResults.TimeDialModerateInverseMin.forEach(function(elt1, i) {

        it('Trip Unit Styles: ' + elt1, function() {
                var Result=   min.filter(function(i) {
                   if(elt1===elt)
                          {
                                 return true;
                          }
                   else
                          {
                          return false;
                          }
             })

             expect(Result.toString()).toContain(elt)

        })

             })

})
```

})

Here i am trying to compare 2 different arrays from 2 different pages.

1. There are 2 files 1.js and range.js
2. 1.js performs operations on the application and stores the data into an array min[].
3. range.js contains expected results which needs to be compared with min[] from 1.js for successfull execution of the TC.

While executing the above code i get an error: "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"
What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Speaking of codestyle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the .forEach functions on two things here. Those are:

`Operation.min` and `ExpectedResults.TimeDialModerateInverseMin`

Your error message is explaining what's happening, one of those two things is undefined (I haven't run the code so don't know which one it's breaking on).

Check that those things are being exported properly from `1.js` and `range.js` by trying to console.log them in this file and check that the keys you're looking for `min` and `TimeDialModerateInverseMin` are in there.

Comment: I figured out what i was doing wrong. had not defined the array where the elements were being stored. therefore forEach function was appearing as not defined.